# Need help assignment and understand nested loops

Tags: java, loops, nested

So the assignment deals with java nested loops which i'm really confused about. I've tried reading textbook and watching videos still not getting it .

Assignment: Use nested loops to create a square and cube table for the numbers 1-10.

Number Square Cube

```
1 1 1

2 4 8

3 9 27

4 16 64

5 25 125

6 36 216

7 49 343

8 64 512

9 81 729

10 100 1000
```

What ive tried(not working)
First Template:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){ // Print 10 rows
    System.out.println( i);
    for(int j = 1; j<= 3; j++){ // Print 3 columns
        System.out.print() // How does j relate to i to get desired numbers on columns?
    }
}
```

I realize there is a way to do without nested loops:

```
for(int i =1; i<=10; i++){
    System.out.println(i+"\t"+i*i+"\t"+i*i*i);
}
```

I'm really stomped at this point since i'm supposed to use nested loops for the assignment and the next assignment would require me to use arrays with nested loops, to let user enter first and last number of the number column.

Comment: You may not need to use nested loops for this, as you observe, but it's clearly homework practice. `i` and `j` aren't related as such - they are just variables.

Answer (score 2):

You need two loops. One for the first number. One for the powers of this number. E.g.:

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){ // Print 10 rows
        for(int j = 1; j<= 3; j++){ // Print 3 columns
                System.out.print(((int)Math.pow(i, j))+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This prints i^1 i^2 i^3 on each line (j being first 1 than 2 than 3).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. Note that a loop doesn't have to loop over consecutive digits. My inner loop exploits that.

```
System.out.println("1 1 1"); // Kludge the first case
for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++){ // Print 10 rows
    for(int j = i; j <= i * i * i; j *= i){ // Iterate up to cube, *= is the smart bit
       System.out.print(j); // Print the number with no newline
    }
    System.out.println(); // Separate the table. An extra line at the end is a bit naughty.
}
```

In more detail, suppose `i` is 4. Then `j` will take the initial value of 4, the next iteration it will be multiplied by 4, (16) then on the last iteration it will be multiplied by 4 again, (64).

Comment: Can you explain how you derived the i and j relationship for the second for loop . I really need to understand and the book doesnt help me at all.

Comment: Added the explanation.

Comment: I think that second for loop is infinite since the j never changes and therefore is always one and never reaches the i * i *i to get to the outer for loop.

Comment: No it terminates. j *= i sets j to the new value, and j is limited to i * i * i

Comment: Tried running the code , however i feel something doesn't change since it goes on an infinite loop on the first row.

Comment: it's because 1*1 = 1 and so does 1*1*...*1. So j is always 1 and is always lesser or equal to 1.

Comment: Oops. I've put in a nasty kludge. Perhaps the homework assignment should better incorporate that into the loop. But I like the elegance of the inner loop.